# Converting a numeric to packed-decimal in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, mainframe

I am building a Native Stored Procedure.. where one of the field is derived by combining(concatenating) 5 values. 3 out of these 5 values are character fields and 2 are packed-decimal. I need to combine them into 1 field before I write into the table.

I am not sure on how can I convert any number to packed decimal (COMP-3 equivalent of COBOL) in a SP.

I tried DEC() function but its not giving expected results.

I'm using DB2 V11

Please let me know if there are any other methods..

Thanks..

Comment: Could you indicate which DBMS are you using?

Comment: IBM DB2 V11 is used

Comment: Please, add a tag or add it to your question.

Comment: Done.. added in the question

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: How would you know whether it as a packed or some other kind of decimal in a stored procedure? Where does the internal representation come into play?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, its just not getting converted.

Comment: How do you know it's not being converted? Show us (in the question) what your code looks like and your expected result from example inputs. If we can't see it, we can't guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
with tmp as 
(
     select 
     case when 
     case when trim(ifnull(valchar1, ''))='' then '0' else trim(valchar1) end  ||
     case when trim(ifnull(valchar2, ''))='' then '0' else trim(valchar2) end  ||
     case when trim(ifnull(valchar3, ''))='' then '0' else trim(valchar3) end  ||
     valdec1 || valdec2 as NewVal
     from your table
)
select 
cast(case NewVal ='' then null else NewVal end as dec(15, 2))  as NewvvalDec 
from tmp
```